# How to make dynamic DOF from mouse position in Unity 5?

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting, depth

I found a video a while ago for how to make a dynamic DOF in unity. It fires rays from the camera and positions an empty at the location that the ray first hit. How can I change this so that it doesn't fire rays from my camera but rather from my mouse position, and then positions the empty from there?

Code:

```
public Transform origin; //Raycast origin
    public GameObject target;

    public CameraMovement cameraMovement;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {
        Ray ray = new Ray(origin.transform.position, origin.transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)){
            Debug.DrawRay(Input.mousePosition, origin.transform.forward, Color.cyan);
            target.transform.position = hit.point;
        }else{
            Debug.DrawRay(Input.mousePosition, origin.transform.forward, Color.red);
        }
    }
```